# How to make python wait until memory is free and then execute next piece of code?

Tags: python, bigdata

I have a class which has methods to save and read CSV or .msgpack files. These files are huge(~3GB) and thus uses a lot of memory.

I am creating an object of this HugeMemoryEatingClass and then i delete this object
before creating another object of the same class to read another file.

```
csvObj = HugeMemoryEatingClass("csv", fileName)
#read/save file, uses a lot of memory
del csvObj

msgObj = HugeMemoryEatingClass("msg", fileName)
msgObj.read() #results into MemoryError
```

The msgObj is created even before the csvObj has been fully deleted and the memory freed up. Thus when i call the msgObj.read() method, it results into a memory error.

I thought deleting the objects will free up the memory.

Is there any way I can free up the memory before python goes to create the msgObj ?

Comment: Python has automatic `Garbage Collection`. So, I don't think you need to worry about deleting objects like in C/C++

Comment: @bigbounty But i need to free up the memory before i can read another huge file!